# looking inside a GdkPixbuf structure with ddd or gdb

Tags: gtk, gdb, gdkpixbuf

i would like to look inside of a GdkPixbuf structure for debugging purposes. but all i get is a `<incomplete type>` message.

ill show you a little snippet of example code.

```
//load image
GtkWidget *image = gtk_image_new_from_file("image.bmp");

//get the GdkPixbuf representation of the image
GdkPixbuf *pixbuff = gtk_image_get_pixbuf(GTK_IMAGE(image));
```

ok now i when i try to look inside the pixbuff structure i get the `<incomplete type>` message. How do i correctly look inside this structure using ddd or gdb debuggers ? im new a coding c and debugging.

ive tried the following in ddd

graph display (GdkPixbuf *)pixbuff
and also right clicking on the variable and using different display options to no avail.

any ideas on how to correctly look inside this structure ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to cast it to `GdkPixbuf *` before printing. See also this question [How to print <incomplete type> variable in gdb](https://stackoverflow.com/q/232744/72178).

```
(gdb) p (GdkPixbuf *)pixbuff
```

Comment: yeah i tried that, i actually wrote that in my post 3rd line from the bottom.

Comment: Have you tried it in gdb? You wrote that you have tried it in ddd.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you how to do this in gdb but if you are open for other ideas, you can try this with *gtkparasite* like this: `GTK_MODULES=gtkparasite yourapp`. If you ever used Spy++ on Windows, it will fit right in.